# Why can't NSSpeechsynthesier's class method availableVoices be bridged to a Swift array of strings?

Tags: swift, cocoa, toll-free-bridging

In Apple's [Working with Cocoa Frameworks](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html) it reads as if the Foundation and Swift Foundation frameworks work together through bridging.  However, I noticed that while attempting to use NSSpeechSynthesizer's class method availableVoices() it allows me to received an returned array of NSStrings but not Strings.

This compiles and runs just fine:

```
let voices = NSSpeechSynthesizer.availableVoices as [NSString]
        print(voices)
```

However this won't compile:

```
let voicesTwo = NSSpeechSynthesizer.availableVoices as [String]
```

Why wouldn't this work if [the voiceName documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsspeechsynthesizer.voicename) shows that VoiceName is a string property?

I see the term 'rawValue' in the VoiceName documentation so is the reasoning having anything to do with this being some sort of an enum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `NSSpeechSynthesizer.VoiceName` is an `Enum` with a `rawValue` of `String`. That is not the same thing as *being* a string.

Try using

```
NSSpeechSynthesizer.availableVoices.map { $0.rawValue }
```